# Afrer Push Notification UIViewController life cycle methods

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I have one problem. After i tap on push notification from my iPhone, my application is opening. But `UIViewController` life cycle methods are not calling. How to call ?
Please Help.

```
-(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
}
```

or

```
-(void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
}
```

Thank You.

Comment: Was your app already running (actually suspended in the background) or was the app freshly started?

Comment: @rmaddy, suspended in the background.
Thank you.

Comment: Then why do you expect those methods to be called again? Your app gets returned to the foreground. That view controller is already in view.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to handle push message, you better use these UIApplicationDelegate methods.

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(3_0);
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(4_0);
```

When your app launched via notification, the delegate will be invoked. Then you do something for your viewController.

Comment: Hi, @trick14 I am thinking that push notification data, will add to my home page TableView. But TableView is not reloading.
Thank you.